# How do I get VDPAU working with Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: video, ubuntu-9.10, htpc, matroska, vdpau

What do I need to do to get [MKV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) HD videos playing with [VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) and also Blu-ray discs?  Lots of people say you need to compile the latest [MPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) (which I haven't had luck doing) for VDPAU.  I found an [mplayer ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/mplayer) that says it has VDPAU compiled into it so I'd like to use that.

What packages do I need for playing MKV files and Blu-ray with the video decoding offloaded to my GPU?  So far I haven't had any luck with any of the tutorials I've found.

I'm just looking for a quick synopsis that will tell me what I'm looking for as I'm kind of shooting in the dark.  (I didn't know what VDPAU was until a few days ago.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, the mplayer ppa actually worked.  I installed that, and smplayer from the same vendor and installed the latest nvidia driver through ubuntu's restricted drivers.  I also installed x264 and ffmpeg (not sure if I needed to or not)

Then in .mplayer/config I put:

```
vo=vdpau
vc=ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau,
```

And in smplayer I had to specifically tell it to run mplayer with vdpau in the options -> video section.

Comment: you can also start files with this in the terminal without having to change the mplayer config file
mplayer -vo vdpau filename.mkv

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest would be to install [XBMC](http://xbmc.org). Download [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=HOW-TO_install_XBMC_for_Linux_on_Ubuntu_with_a_minimal_installation_step-by-step). It is loosly based on MPlayer (or it was...) and [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) but has all the codecs and options like VDPAU available and compiled in.

It's a lot bulkier than just MPlayer, but it will cover all the possible bases.

Of course to play Blu-ray they will have to be decrypted first (or use a script with makemkv)

Don't forget, you HAVE to have a compatible **nVidia** GPU. That's 8xxx or newer.

Some more information here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD

Comment: thx for the tip.  Do you have to install any extra codec packages for this?  I don't really know how it works with players in Linux, do they come with codecs or do I manually install them?

Comment: updated answer, butyes all the codecs are in the PPA

Comment: I ended up installing the ppa for mplayer and installed the latest NVidia drivers (I have a 9400M GPU) and it worked like a charm!!  I checked out XBMC but it seemed a bit too bulky (as you mentioned)  Thought I'd stick with the much smaller mplayer.  Thanks though!

Comment: ION? Acer revo by any chance? :) very nice media platform those. I have the 9300M in a ASUS LGA775 socket mobo. an old celeron conroe-L single core 35w cpu underclocked to 1.4G. with VDPAU for media it JUST FLIES!

Answer (score 0):

vdpau support entered ffmpeg mainline in 2009 but Ubuntu has not seen fit to build it in to Lucid. It's a compile-time flag. Presumably it makes ffmpeg depend on libvdpau, so what is needed is two packages (ffmpeg and ffmpeg-vdpau) which both provide ffmpeg-decoder, or similar. libvdpau could recommend ffmpeg-vdpau.